# Play mp3 file that is stored in the assets directory in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, uri, assets, file-descriptor

I am trying with the code form Android MediaPlayer overview:

val myUri: Uri = .... // initialize Uri here

val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {

```
setAudioAttributes(
    AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .build()
)

setDataSource(applicationContext, myUri)

prepare()

start()
```

}

How do I get the Uri for my file?
The documentation suggests "...here is how you might play from a URI available locally in the system (that you obtained through a Content Resolver, for instance)"
What is Content Resolver and how do I use it?

Comment: For `MediaPlayer`, IIRC, you are better off with a raw resource than with an asset.

Comment: I have more than 4000 audio clips - the total mb is more than what I can put in raw resources